# Would I do okay in a Chess tournament with 1500 chess.com rating?

Tags: tournament

Here is the background story before I get into my actual question. There is a chess tournament in a city near mine, starting at 28th of August. The thing is, my parents won't allow me to go there. Not because they don't want to. We end our vacations in 29, so we spend one day less. I say, can I go alone there(I am with some friends and my FM trainer), they say no because they don't know them really well. When I say that dad or the entire family can come, they say no because of the vacations. I live in a country with not so many tournaments, and this is both cheap, and near, for it. Now that you understand my predicament, I want to know if all the trouble of convincing my parents is worth it; the tournament is open and I have a 1500 chess.com rating, so I was wondering if the chess tournament would be a good fit for my score?

On a side note can you guys think of any ways on how to convince them to let me go? Let me know how you convinced your parents to let you go somewhere, and what is the best score to go to a tournament if 1500 is not okay. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not a chess question! Try http://parenting.stackexchange.com/ perhaps.

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that this is a question and answer site, *not* a discussion site.

Comment: Some modifications were made to make this question acceptable. Please reconsider.

Comment: This is not a substantial improvement.

Comment: @MikhailTal If you're going to ask a completely different question ("Would a chess tournament improve my skills more than Chess.com?") than what your original question was ("Making parents to let you join a chess tournament"), it is better to simply ask a new question and not edit the old one, because the comments and answers here are for the original question.

Comment: An user idea. I want to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let them know how much this tournament means to you and how much you will save by going to this tournament rather than one back home. Convincing parents isn't exactly the easiest and I am well aware of this but if you are able to make them consider the facts about this tournament you should be fine. Ex:

1. Letting them know that the tournament ends that day at a specific time, this will allow them to assess their schedule and see whether or not your tournament interferes with their plans.
2. Discuss with them that the cost is fairly cheap and as such it would be almost a crime  not to attend!
3. Relate the tournament with the vacation, perhaps this annual tournament has lots of history and is a huge attraction during this time of the year.

These are just examples of what you can say to convince your parents. As for your chess rating I haven't done any real tournaments myself and I am not sure how your rating on chess.com will do against actual players in a live setting. Overall it doesn't sound bad at all, and you should use this experience to become a better player. I wish you good luck with these tasks.

Comment: Thanks, will try these tommorow, if they work you get a check. If ither people have ideas, I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: Sounds good take all things into consideration!

Comment: As for the rating, I think the tournament experience is good regardless of your rating.  If you do well, consider yourself fortunate AND congratulate yourself on your preparation; if you don't, remember that playing in a tournament can affect how comfortable you are with your playing and how well you think about the games.  Good luck.